# How to consistently hot encode dataframes with changing values?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm getting a stream of content in the form of dataframes, each batch with different values in columns. 
For example one batch might look like:

```
day1_data = {'state': ['MS', 'OK', 'VA', 'NJ', 'NM'], 
            'city': ['C', 'B', 'G', 'Z', 'F'], 
            'age': [27, 19, 63, 40, 93]}
```

and another one like:

```
day2_data = {'state': ['AL', 'WY', 'VA'], 
            'city': ['A', 'B', 'E'], 
            'age': [42, 52, 73]}
```

how can the columns be hot encoded in a way that returns a consistent number of columns?

If I use pandas's get_dummies() on each of the batches, it returns a different number of columns:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(day1_data))
df2 = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(day2_data))

len(df1.columns) == len(df2.columns)
```

I can get all the possible values for each column, the question is even with that information what's the simplest way to generate the one hot encoding for each daily batch so the number of columns will be consistent?

Comment: Both of you data sources have the same columns `age`, `city`, and `state`. Is this always the case? If not, please provide a more realistic example with different columns.

Comment: Interesting question. Do you know ALL the values a particular column could contain in advance?

Comment: Why not just concatenate them and then call get dummies?

Comment: @akilat90 Yes all values are pre-known - at the moment I'm using something very hackish where I look at the columns of a synthetic dataframe I generated that has all values and add the intersection its 'get_dummies' with any new dataframe that comes - it's very ugly - wondering what would be a better way to do this

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ because there's no guarantee that the dataframes you have got so far have all values to be seen in the future, and the likelihood of missing values in the first period of time (~1st month) will be very high

Comment: @MikeMüller yes the dataframes always have the same columns, but different values which is what's causing the  issue

Comment: Ok So lets make this clear. You will have only same columns always (age, city, state) and you know all the possible values they can take (city= {'A', 'B'...'Z'} and state = {'MS','NY', ...'AZ'} and no values from outside those. Am I correct?

Comment: @VivekKumar exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay since all the possible values are known in advance. Then below is a slightly hackish way of doing it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# This is a one time process
# Keep all the possible data here in lists
# Can add other categorical variables too which have this type of data
all_possible_states=  ['AL', 'MS', 'MS', 'OK', 'VA', 'NJ', 'NM', 'CD', 'WY']
all_possible_cities= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'Z', 'F']

# Declare our transformer class
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

class MyOneHotEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, all_possible_values):
        self.le = LabelEncoder()
        self.ohe = OneHotEncoder()
        self.ohe.fit(self.le.fit_transform(all_possible_values).reshape(-1,1))

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return self.ohe.transform(self.le.transform(X).reshape(-1,1)).toarray()

# Allow the transformer to see all the data here
encoders = {}
encoders['state'] = MyOneHotEncoder(all_possible_states)
encoders['city'] = MyOneHotEncoder(all_possible_cities)
# Do this for all categorical columns

# Now this is our method which will be used on the incoming data 
def encode(df):

    tup = (encoders['state'].transform(df['state']), 
           encoders['city'].transform(df['city']),
           # Add all other columns which are not to be transformed
           df[['age']])

    return np.hstack(tup)

# Testing:
day1_data = pd.DataFrame({'state': ['MS', 'OK', 'VA', 'NJ', 'NM'], 
        'city': ['C', 'B', 'G', 'Z', 'F'], 
        'age': [27, 19, 63, 40, 93]})

print(encode(day1_data))
[[  0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.  27.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.  19.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    1.   0.  63.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   1.  40.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.
    0.   0.  93.]]


day2_data = pd.DataFrame({'state': ['AL', 'WY', 'VA'], 
            'city': ['A', 'B', 'E'], 
            'age': [42, 52, 73]})

print(encode(day2_data))
[[  1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.  42.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.  52.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   0.
    0.   0.  73.]]
```

Do go through the comments and if still any issue, ask me.