# Create a custom sklearn TransformerMixin that transforms categorical variables consistently

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034035/how-to-consistently-hot-encode-dataframes-with-changing-values) as someone suggested. Why? Because in that example, all possible values ARE KNOWN. In this example, they aren't. Further, this question - in addition to using a custom converter on unknown values - is asking specifically how to perform the transform in the same exact way as the initial transform. Once again I can tell I'll have to answer my own question eventually.

---

When creating a custom scikit-learn transformer, how can you guarantee or "force" the transform method to output only the columns it was fitted with originally?

Below illustrates. This is my example transformer.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

class DFTransformer(TransformerMixin):

    def fit(self, df, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def transform(self, df, **trans_params):
        self.df = df
        self.STACKER = pd.DataFrame()

        for col in self.df:
            dtype = self.df[col].dtype.name
            if dtype == 'object':
                self.STACKER = pd.concat([self.STACKER, self.get_dummies(col)], axis=1)
            elif dtype == 'int64':
                self.STACKER = pd.concat([self.STACKER, self.cut_it(col)], axis=1)

        return self.STACKER

    def get_dummies(self, name):
        return pd.get_dummies(self.df[name], prefix=name)

    def cut_it(self, name, bins=5):
        s = self.df[name].copy()
        return pd.get_dummies(pd.cut(s, bins), prefix=name)
```

Here's some dummy data. One of my methods uses `pd.cut` in-efforts to bin large ranges of ints or floats. Another method uses `pd.get_dummies` which turns unique values into columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'integers': np.random.randint(2000, 20000, 30, dtype='int64'),
                   'categorical': np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'), 30)},
                  columns=['integers', 'categorical'])

trans = DFTransformer()
X = trans.fit_transform(df)
y = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 30)
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)

X_test = pd.DataFrame({'integers': np.random.randint(2000, 60000, 30, dtype='int64'),
                   'categorical': np.random.choice(list('ABGIOPXYZ'), 30)},
                  columns=['integers', 'categorical'])
lr.predict(trans.transform(X_test))
```

The issue I'm having is that when I go and transform the "test" data (the data I'd like to make predictions on), it's highly likely that the conversion won't output the same exact columns due to the different categorical values (ex: obscure values that maybe appear once and then are never seen or heard from again).

For example, the above code produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myname/Downloads/SO009949884.py", line 44, in <module>
    lr.predict(trans.transform(X_test))
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 324, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 305, in decision_function
    % (X.shape[1], n_features))
ValueError: X has 14 features per sample; expecting 20
```

**Question**: how do I go about ensuring my transform method transforms my test data the same way?

One bad solution I can think of is: transform training data, transform testing data, see where columns intersect, modify my transform function to limit output to those columns. Or, fill in blank columns for those that are missing. This is not scalable. Surely there's a better way? I don't want to have to know what the output columns must be before-hand.

**My overall goal** is to convert categorical variables in a consistent way across train and test datasets. I have 150+ columns to transform!

Comment: If you can, please use the [CategoricalEncoder instead](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html) which is present in current development branch. Else see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48095698/3374996)

Comment: pd.get_dummies() is only recommended when you use it on whole data and then split. Not the other way round.

Comment: @VivekKumar what difference does it make if get_dummies is used vs CategoricalEncoder? Is there some advantageous difference that assists the transform process when applied to test data? I don't see how your suggestion solves for the problem here which is that some values in the test data are non-existent and/or the test data has values that the train data transform didn't have.

Comment: pd.get_dummies will return different columns when used on different data, so using it after splitting will obviously return different number of columns and same problem as you are facing now.

Comment: CategoricalEncoder will take care of that and will match the number of columns to the training data if test data have some categories missing. But if test data have some new catgory, it will and should throw error because it doesnt make any sense to test data on which model wasn't trained.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I'll let your comments sit with me for a while and give CategoricalEncoder a go soon.

Comment: I made a blog post to address this: https://blog.pursuitofzen.com/categorygrouper-handling-unknown-categories-for-scikit-learn/

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Nice approach! That concept makes a lot of sense. Next time I'm in this situation, I hope I remember this. Could you post that as an answer by chance (so I can look back to this question)?

Comment: @Jarad Not a problem! I just added my answer and provided an example of using the transformer.

Comment: re: get_dummies, if you make sure to use pandas' CategoricalDType with the categories explicitly given, you can guarantee that get_dummies will have consistent shape.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made a blog post to address this. Below is the transformer I built.

```
class CategoryGrouper(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):  
    """A tranformer for combining low count observations for categorical features.

    This transformer will preserve category values that are above a certain
    threshold, while bucketing together all the other values. This will fix issues
    where new data may have an unobserved category value that the training data
    did not have.
    """

    def __init__(self, threshold=0.05):
        """Initialize method.

        Args:
            threshold (float): The threshold to apply the bucketing when
                categorical values drop below that threshold.
        """
        self.d = defaultdict(list)
        self.threshold = threshold

    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        """Transforms X with new buckets.

        Args:
            X (obj): The dataset to pass to the transformer.

        Returns:
            The transformed X with grouped buckets.
        """
        X_copy = X.copy()
        for col in X_copy.columns:
            X_copy[col] = X_copy[col].apply(lambda x: x if x in self.d[col] else 'CategoryGrouperOther')
        return X_copy

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        """Fits transformer over X.

        Builds a dictionary of lists where the lists are category values of the
        column key for preserving, since they meet the threshold.
        """
        df_rows = len(X.index)
        for col in X.columns:
            calc_col = X.groupby(col)[col].agg(lambda x: (len(x) * 1.0) / df_rows)
            self.d[col] = calc_col[calc_col >= self.threshold].index.tolist()
        return self
```

Basically, the motivation originally came from me having to handle sparse category values, but then I realized this could be applied to unknown values. The transformer essentially groups sparse category values together, given a threshold, so since unknown values would inherit 0% of the value space, they would get bucketed into a `CategoryGrouperOther` group.

Here's just a demonstration of the transformer:

```
# dfs with 100 elements in cat1 and cat2
# note how df_test has elements 'g' and 't' in the respective categories (unknown values)
df_train = pd.DataFrame({'cat1': ['a'] * 20 + ['b'] * 30 + ['c'] * 40 + ['d'] * 3 + ['e'] * 4 + ['f'] * 3,
                         'cat2': ['z'] * 25 + ['y'] * 25 + ['x'] * 25 + ['w'] * 20 +['v'] * 5})
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'cat1': ['a'] * 10 + ['b'] * 20 + ['c'] * 5 + ['d'] * 50 + ['e'] * 10 + ['g'] * 5,
                        'cat2': ['z'] * 25 + ['y'] * 55 + ['x'] * 5 + ['w'] * 5 + ['t'] * 10})

catgrouper = CategoryGrouper()
catgrouper.fit(df_train)
df_test_transformed = catgrouper.transform(df_test)

df_test_transformed

    cat1    cat2
0   a   z
1   a   z
2   a   z
3   a   z
4   a   z
5   a   z
6   a   z
7   a   z
8   a   z
9   a   z
10  b   z
11  b   z
12  b   z
13  b   z
14  b   z
15  b   z
16  b   z
17  b   z
18  b   z
19  b   z
20  b   z
21  b   z
22  b   z
23  b   z
24  b   z
25  b   y
26  b   y
27  b   y
28  b   y
29  b   y
... ... ...
70  CategoryGrouperOther    y
71  CategoryGrouperOther    y
72  CategoryGrouperOther    y
73  CategoryGrouperOther    y
74  CategoryGrouperOther    y
75  CategoryGrouperOther    y
76  CategoryGrouperOther    y
77  CategoryGrouperOther    y
78  CategoryGrouperOther    y
79  CategoryGrouperOther    y
80  CategoryGrouperOther    x
81  CategoryGrouperOther    x
82  CategoryGrouperOther    x
83  CategoryGrouperOther    x
84  CategoryGrouperOther    x
85  CategoryGrouperOther    w
86  CategoryGrouperOther    w
87  CategoryGrouperOther    w
88  CategoryGrouperOther    w
89  CategoryGrouperOther    w
90  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
91  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
92  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
93  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
94  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
95  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
96  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
97  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
98  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
99  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
```

Even works when I set threshold to 0 (this will exclusively set unknown values to the 'other' group while preserving all the other category values). I would caution against setting threshold to 0 though, because your training dataset would not have the 'other' category so tweak the threshold to flag at least one value to be the 'other' group:

```
catgrouper = CategoryGrouper(threshold=0)
catgrouper.fit(df_train)
df_test_transformed = catgrouper.transform(df_test)

df_test_transformed

    cat1    cat2
0   a   z
1   a   z
2   a   z
3   a   z
4   a   z
5   a   z
6   a   z
7   a   z
8   a   z
9   a   z
10  b   z
11  b   z
12  b   z
13  b   z
14  b   z
15  b   z
16  b   z
17  b   z
18  b   z
19  b   z
20  b   z
21  b   z
22  b   z
23  b   z
24  b   z
25  b   y
26  b   y
27  b   y
28  b   y
29  b   y
... ... ...
70  d   y
71  d   y
72  d   y
73  d   y
74  d   y
75  d   y
76  d   y
77  d   y
78  d   y
79  d   y
80  d   x
81  d   x
82  d   x
83  d   x
84  d   x
85  e   w
86  e   w
87  e   w
88  e   w
89  e   w
90  e   CategoryGrouperOther
91  e   CategoryGrouperOther
92  e   CategoryGrouperOther
93  e   CategoryGrouperOther
94  e   CategoryGrouperOther
95  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
96  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
97  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
98  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
99  CategoryGrouperOther    CategoryGrouperOther
```

Comment: Blog post is link is dead. (Says 503, but probably not actually temporary unless something is fixed.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks for the notice. Yes, the link is dead along with the entire blog due to the hosting service making changes. I have to spin up another blog instance and migrate the data from the old blog to the new one.

Comment: Hi, is there any plan in updating the blog or is there the content anywhere? @Scratch

Comment: @invertedOwlCoding Unfortunately the data for my blog was nuked by the service when I tried to create a new Ghost service with my hosting provider. Is there any question you have regarding my answer?

Comment: @scratch Aw.. that is sad. It seem like you had good content there. I am just building my own code base and looking around for nuggets like that. Know anywhere else that I can poke around?

Comment: @invertedOwlCoding I have a new blog at pursuitofzen.com but it's leaning more towards software/web development since I do more of that nowadays. What are you building, if I may ask?

Comment: @scratch thanks, will check. i am currently still in the exploratory phase and looking to make a pipeline for accurate reads of the data, so custom transformers and pipeline is kind of in the alley right now..

Answer (score 2):

And like I said, answering my own question. Here's the solution I'm going with for now.

```
def get_datasets(df):
    trans1= DFTransformer()
    trans2= DFTransformer()
    train = trans1.fit_transform(df.iloc[:, :-1])
    test = trans2.fit_transform(pd.read_pickle(TEST_PICKLE_PATH))
    columns = train.columns.intersection(test.columns).tolist()
    X_train = train[columns]
    y_train = df.iloc[:, -1]
    X_test = test[columns]
    return X_train, y_train, X_test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about your `pd.get_dummies()` outputting the wrong dimensions you could simply specify the categorical encoding for your columns.

For example:

```
fit_df = pd.DataFrame({'COUNTRY': ['UK', 'FR', 'IT']}, dtype='category')
fit_categories = fit_df.COUNTRY.cat.categories

predict_df = pd.DataFrame({'COUNTRY': ['UK']}, dtype='category')
predict_df.COUNTRY = predict_df.COUNTRY.cat.set_categories(fit_categories)
pd.get_dummies(predict_df)
```

Will return the following table:

```
   COUNTRY_FR    COUNTRY_IT    COUNTRY_UK
            0             0             1
```

So in your case, you could simply define your categorical encoding in a config file or have the transformer class track the initial encoding.

This approach could also be extended to handle unseen categorical values by using `pd.Series.cat.add_categories`

Hope this helps.

See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.set_categories.html#pandas.Series.cat.set_categories) for more information.